# `Heroku pg:backups capture` gives "Resource not found" error

Tags: postgresql, heroku, pg

When running this command - either locally or through Codeship.io - I get an error message saying `"Resource not found"`

```
$ heroku pg:backups capture
 !    Resource not found
```

The problem started 2 days ago and thus my first guess was that it's because of the transfer from the old to the new PGBackups on Heroku ([mapping guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/mapping-pgbackups-commands)). 
This is *not* the case, the command syntax is already in the new format.

For reference my local toolbelt version:

```
$ heroku version
heroku-toolbelt/3.33.0 (x86_64-darwin10.8.0) ruby/1.9.3
You have no installed plugins.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to specify your database. For example, if you use ROSE:

`heroku pg:backups capture HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_ROSE`